# Simplest Possible Performance Counter Example

Tags: c#, performancecounter

What is the smallest amount of C# code to get a performance counter up and running?

I simply want to measure the number of CPU cycles and/or time between two points in my code.  I've skimmed through all the waffle on the web but it seems like WAY more code than is necessary for such a trivial task.  I just want to get a quick measurement up and running and concentrate more on what I'm working on.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think you need a performance counter for that. Do you need more than the timing you can get from [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) ? It is very accurate.

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Do work

watch.Stop();
// elapsed time is in watch.Elapsed
```

However, to answer the question you actually asked: If you just want to query existing counters, it is in fact quite simple. Here is a full example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

static class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var processorCategory = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()
            .FirstOrDefault(cat => cat.CategoryName == "Processor");
        var countersInCategory = processorCategory.GetCounters("_Total");

        DisplayCounter(countersInCategory.First(cnt => cnt.CounterName == "% Processor Time"));
    }

    private static void DisplayCounter(PerformanceCounter performanceCounter)
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1} = {2}",
                performanceCounter.CategoryName, performanceCounter.CounterName, performanceCounter.NextValue());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the process will need appropiate permissions to access the performance counters you need.

Comment: Perhaps I should have elaborated that I was trying to implement a simple Regex engine.  Will the stop watch be accurate enough for that?

Comment: @Paul Matthews - it will fine. The stopwatch resolution is in ticks

Comment: It is accurate enough for measuring performance of your code, if that's what you are asking. Remember to run code in Release mode outside Visual Studio if you are measuring performance. Also, I would recommend you use a profiler to measure performance, it will tell you a lot more about your code's performance than just a simple point-to-point time measurement.

Comment: Q: Simplest way to use Performance Counters? A: Don't!  (lol :)

Comment: Best answer to a question never asked ever.

Comment: This is broken example: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'PerformanceCounterCategory' does not exist in the current context MyPerfCounter C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyPerfCounter\MyPerfCounter\Program.cs 9 Active

Answer (score 12):

I like something that can take any code block and wrap it with stopwatch profiling code to measure time spent executing it:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;

    public static T Profile<T>(Func<T> codeBlock, string description = "")
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        T res = codeBlock();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        const double thresholdSec = 2;
        double elapsed = ts.TotalSeconds;
        if(elapsed > thresholdSec)
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(description + " code was too slow! It took " +
             elapsed + " second(s).");
        return res;
    }
```

Then call it like that:

```
    Profile(() => MyObj.MySlowMethod());
```

or:

```
    Profile(() => MyObj.MySlowMethod(), "I can explain why");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no *trivial* way to get this up and running in .NET. However, the simplest way I've found is to build on top of the Enterprise Library which provides some out of the box capabilities for working with performance counters. For example: [the Performance Counter Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648626.aspx)

The Enterprise Library also gives you some capabilities for much more easily managing the installation of performance counters.

Additionally, it let's you build on top of it so, you can create an AvergeTimeMeter which allows you to just do this:

```
private static EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounter averageRequestTimeCounter = PerformanceCounterManager.GetEnterpriseLibraryCounter(MadPerformanceCountersListener.AverageRequestTime);
private static EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounter averageRequestTimeCounterBase = PerformanceCounterManager.GetEnterpriseLibraryCounter(MadPerformanceCountersListener.AverageRequestTimeBase);

public void DoSomethingWeWantToMonitor()
{
    using (new AverageTimeMeter(averageRequestTimeCounter, averageRequestTimeCounterBase))
    {
        // code here that you want to perf mon
    }
}
```

This allows you to simply encapsulate the code you want to monitor in a using block - and concentrate on the code you actually want to work on rather than worrying about all the performance counter infrastructure.

To do this, you'll create a re-usable AverageTimeMeter class like this:

```
public sealed class AverageTimeMeter : IDisposable
{
    private EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounter averageCounter;
    private EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounter baseCounter;
    private Stopwatch stopWatch;
    private string instanceName;

    public AverageTimeMeter(EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounter averageCounter, EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounter baseCounter, string instanceName = null)
    {
        this.stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        this.averageCounter = averageCounter;
        this.baseCounter = baseCounter;
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
        this.stopWatch.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.stopWatch.Stop();
        if (this.baseCounter != null)
        {
            this.baseCounter.Increment();
        }

        if (this.averageCounter != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.instanceName))
            {
                this.averageCounter.IncrementBy(this.stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
            }
            else
            {
                this.averageCounter.SetValueFor(this.instanceName, this.averageCounter.Value + this.stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You have to register your performance counters (shown in the EntLib examples) but this should get your started.

Comment: Based on the comments I'm now seeing above, it looks like perhaps your question was more related to measuring code and not so much *specifically* for performance counters. I always the question specifically from the perspective of performance counters - if you don't need this, this I agree Stopwatch is the simplest way to go.

Comment: The last time I used performance counters was in Delphi so maybe the terminology has changed a little.  Sorry if I led you up the garden path :)